# Best way to multiprocessing or call some functions parallel

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I'm working on a tool that opens some instances of Mozilla Firefox, using Selenium Webdriver.
There are three instances that loading the same page in the same time.
Due to the slow loading of the pages with Web Driver, I want to load the relevant page in all the browsers parallel.

My code today looks like this:

```
browser1 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser2 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser3 = webdriver.Firefox()

browser1.get('http://google.com')
browser2.get('http://google.com')
browser3.get('http://google.com')
```

In that code for example, `browser2` will load only after `browser1` will finish his loading.
I'm looking for a way to load all of the three browsers parallel.

**Note** - I need to join them all, means that the code will continue only when the three browsers will load successfully

Thanks ahead

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will work (can not check it right now), but you should try:

```
from Multiprocessing import Process
def first_browser():
  browser1 = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser1.get('http://google.com')
def second_browser():
  browser2 = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser2.get('http://google.com')
def third_browser():
  browser3 = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser3.get('http://google.com')
p1 = Process(target=first_browser)
p2 = Process(target=second_browser)
p3 = Process(target=third_browser)
```

Comment: How can I do a "join" method that waits for all the three to load?

Comment: wait till all browsers complete to load `Google` page to start new action or load what?

Comment: wait to start new action, for example to take page_source of all of them

Comment: you want next action to start simultaneously on all browsers (to 
synchronize actions on all browsers) or just start for each browser after page load?

Comment: Each browser separately after load.

Comment: just add new actions to appropriate function body